# CSS hover Not working in Google Chrome when running the file using a server

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hover

The hover css function is not working on google chrome when i run my html file in wamp server. I tried it in internet explorer then it works fine. When i open the file without using the server it works fine in chrome. It only occurs when i run it using the server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<title></title>

<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://localhost/voted.php?vote=1"><div class="vote1"></div></a>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my css file

```
vote1:hover a{
width: 50px; 
height: 50px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: Black;
background: url('H:/Site/haride/Images/x.jpg')repeat-x right top;
}
 .vote1 {
display: block;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
position: absolute;
top: 450px;
left: 148px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: Black;
}
```

Comment: you are using local path 'H:/Site/haride/Images/x.jpg'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS is structured incorrectly. The correct syntax for your hover link is

```
a div.vote1:hover {
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/L44fwpv7/

And your calling a local file as others mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS has a hard link to a file on a disk:

```
background: url('H:/Site/haride/Images/x.jpg')repeat-x right top;
```

Remove h:/Site/haride and create an `Images` folder in your web site project and copy the x.jpg file to that folder.

Not everyone visiting your website will have access to H:/Site, but they will have access to the subfolder /Images